# How to Move Google Cloud SDK Directory

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud

I mistakenly installed the Google Cloud SDK to the wrong directory on my local machine (I installed it to my Google Drive folder, which is not ideal). What is the preferred method of moving the folder? I haven't tried anything yet for fear of creating issues with environment variables that may have been set during installation. I'm running OS X on my local machine.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The Cloud SDK is *self contained*, and so the **google-cloud-sdk** directory can generally be moved to wherever you like. The only thing that is configured outside that directory is your `~/.bash_profile` file (only if you said yes during the installation process) which adds the SDK to your PATH and installs command tab completion.  If you had the installer update that, probably the easiest thing to do is just delete the google-cloud-sdk directory entirely and reinstall in the location you want.  The installer will re-update your `~/.bash_profile` with the new location.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up moving the directory and updating in bash_profile. It worked out perfectly.

Comment: for the record, the configuration is written to .bashrc on Debian installations

Comment: There may be other installation artifacts, e.g. you may also need to update the cmd-path in ~/.kube/config

Comment: What about Windows?

Answer (score 1):

for zsh,  just move the folder to desired location and update `.zshrc`, check for following lines and set new path:

```
# The next line updates PATH for the Google Cloud SDK.
... path.zsh.inc ...

# The next line enables shell command completion for gcloud.
... completion.zsh.inc ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the magic script.. just change the PREV_DIR & NEW_DIR variables

```
PREV_DIR=/Users/some_user/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk
NEW_DIR=/Users/some_user/google-cloud-sdk

function z(){
  if test -f "$1"; then; sed -i "" -e "s#$PREV_DIR#$NEW_DIR#g" $1 ; fi
}

z ~/.zshrc
z ~/.zprofile
z ~/.bashrc
z ~/.bash_profile
z ~/.kube/config
```